# NPOI with ASP.NET (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, npoi

I am trying to get NPOI to work with ASP.NET (C#) and I want to read an excel file and put it in a DataSet.  Here is the code I  attempted:

```
public static DataTable getExcelData(string FileName, string strSheetName)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    HSSFWorkbook hssfworkbook;
    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        hssfworkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    }

    ISheet sheet = hssfworkbook.GetSheet(strSheetName);
    System.Collections.IEnumerator rows = sheet.GetRowEnumerator();

    while (rows.MoveNext())
    {
        IRow row = (HSSFRow)rows.Current;

        if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < row.LastCellNum; j++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(row.GetCell(j).ToString());
            }

            continue;
        }

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < row.LastCellNum; i++)
        {
            ICell cell = row.GetCell(i);

            if (cell == null)
            {
                dr[i] = null;
            }
            else
            {
                dr[i] = cell.ToString();
            }
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

The Error that I get is

```
+       $exception  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}   System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}
```

The odd thing is that this actually works with 2 excel files that I have, but when I put in a third one it crashes with that error.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using also `FirstCellNum` instead of `0`?

Comment: Likely you're hitting ICell's that don't exist.  Remember with NPOI that each cell must be individually created, ones that aren't created would be `null`.  Also, what line did the exception occur on?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @ebyrob on System.Collections.IEnumerator rows = sheet.GetRowEnumerator();

Comment: @Bagzli In that case strSheetName didn't match what you have in the document...  Be sure to check for extra white space.

Comment: @ebyrob you absolutely correct, I cannot believe I have overlooked that. Thank you! Could you post that as an answer please so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns `null` if strSheetName isn't found:

```
ISheet sheet = hssfworkbook.GetSheet(strSheetName);
```

try:

```
for( int iSheet = 0; iSheet < hssfworkbook.NumberOfSheets; ++iSheet )
{
    ISheet sheet = hssfworkbook.GetSheetAt(iSheet); // could cast to HSSFSheet
    String strSheetNameActual = sheet.SheetName;
}
```

Then figure out how you want to compare `strSheetName` to `strSheetNameActual` or which sheets you want to process and how.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
for (int j = row.FirstCellNum; j < row.LastCellNum; j++)
```

and

```
for (int i = row.FirstCellNum; i < row.LastCellNum; i++)
```

Instead of:

```
for (int j = 0; j < row.LastCellNum; j++)
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < row.LastCellNum; i++)
```

Also, make sure that you manage the case when the cells on the first row are `null`:

```
if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
{
    int empty = 0;
    for (int j = row.FirstCellNum; j < row.LastCellNum; j++)
    {
        ICell cell = row.GetCell(j);
        if (cell == null)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(String.Format("emptyColumnName_{0}", empty++));
        }
        else
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(row.GetCell(j).ToString());
        }
    }
    continue;
}
```

If you always want to read from the first sheet (probably, to get rid of the second method parameter, the sheet name, which is also the cause of your error), you may use:

```
// rest of the method's code
ISheet sheet = hssfworkbook.GetSheetAt(0);
if (sheet == null)
    return dt;
var rows = sheet.GetRowEnumerator();
// rest of the method's code
```

Comment: What about for (int i = 0; i < row.LastCellNum; i++) ?  I tried it your way and still the same thing.  I don't think that is the problem, yet anyways, because the code breaks before it ever reaches that line.  It brakes on this line:  System.Collections.IEnumerator rows = sheet.GetRowEnumerator();

Comment: So what you posted was not exactly the correct answer but I do see your points so I will add some stuff to improve my code, so thank you for that.

Comment: When I posted the answer I didn't have the info about the exact line where you go the exception... Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: yeah I realize that, thanks for trying to help me out though; I really appreciate it.  The other question I wanted to ask was how do I get the name of the first sheet in an xls file using NPOI?  I cannot figure that out for the life of me.  I'm not sure if I should just put a new question up or I can ask here.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Hvala!